# Ubuntu 15.10 cannot unmount file system on shutdown

Tags: filesystem, shutdown, 15.10, unmount

My Asus Ux303 laptop cannot shutdown, because it hangs at unmounting the filesystem.

It hangs at Unmounting local filesystem...

Any ideas what could cause this or how to diagnose it?

[image: shutdown hang picture]

Comment: Can you upload the output of `dmesg` directly after you booted the machine again after it hanged at shutdown? Use e.g. https://www.pastebin.org please.

Comment: sure, : http://pastebin.com/Pc32Kpvh

Comment: On my 14.04 machine with upstart, that message comes from  `/etc/rc6. d/S40unmountfs`  , and second entry after that is `fstab-decode umount -f -r -d $REG_MTPTS` which could be potentially the issue. Problem is 15.10  uses different init system, `systemd` so the script for that might not have been ported properly . . . I'd suggest asking this question on Unix & Linux stackexchange as there's more systemd knowledgeable folks